# Can't fix missing directive/assembly error in Unity/C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm copying a template to the T, and my code referencing another script in my unity assets with my controls wont compile; however, I think it's me making an error in my file names rather than a misspelled or miscapitilized word. Any directions in where to look?

Assets\NewBehaviourScript.cs(27,13): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PlayerControls' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(PlayerInput))]



public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float playerSpeed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private float gravityValue = -9.81f;
    [SerializeField] private float controllerDeadzone = 0.1f;
    [SerializeField] private float gamepadrotateSmoothing = 1000f; 

    [SerializeField] private bool isGamepad; 

    private CharacterController controller;

    private Vector2 movement;
    private Vector2 aim;

    private Vector3 playerVelocity;
    
    private PlayerControls playerControls;
    private PlayerInput playerInput;


    private void Awake ()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        playerControls = new PlayerControls();
        playerInput = GetComponent<playerInput>();
    }


    private void OnEnable()
    {
        playerControls.Enable();

    }

private void OnDisable()
    {
        PlayerControls.Disable();
    }
  

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        HandleInput();
        HandleMovement();
        HandleRotation();
    }

    void HandleInput()
    {
        movement = playerControls.Controls.Movement.ReadValue<Vector2>
        aim = Playercontrols.ControlsActions.Aim.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    }

    void HandleMovement()
    {
        Vector3 move = new Vector3(movement.x, 0, movement.y);
        controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);

        playerVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void HandleRotation()
    {

    }

}
```

\\ second script for clarity

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem.Utilities;

public partial class @PlayerControls : IInputActionCollection2, IDisposable
{
    public InputActionAsset asset { get; }
    public @PlayerControls()
    {
        asset = InputActionAsset.FromJson(@"{
    ""name"": ""player controls"",
    ""maps"": [
        {
            ""name"": ""Controls"",
            ""id"": ""8caed008-db15-4a57-ad55-4ef6833f51c5"",
            ""actions"": [
                {
                    ""name"": ""Movement"",
                    ""type"": ""PassThrough"",
                    ""id"": ""ba3cbd10-0b44-4fa9-b84a-b46399ecb977"",
                    ""expectedControlType"": ""Vector2"",
                    ""processors"": """",
                    ""interactions"": """",
                    ""initialStateCheck"": false
                },
                {
                    ""name"": ""Aim"",
                    ""type"": ""PassThrough"",
                    ""id"": ""d37d46e3-53d7-46cb-b352-41aa2d9a773d"",
                    ""expectedControlType"": ""Vector2"",
                    ""processors"": """",
                    ""interactions"": """",
                    ""initialStateCheck"": false
                }
            ],
            ""bindings"": [
                {
                    ""name"": """",
                    ""id"": ""182e6d62-b43d-4a6d-a609-74ed42dda3bc"",
                    ""path"": ""<Gamepad>/leftStick"",
                    ""interactions"": """",
                    ""processors"": """",
                    ""groups"": ""gamepad"",
                    ""action"": ""Movement"",
                    ""isComposite"": false,
                    ""isPartOfComposite"": false
                },
                {
                    ""name"": ""WASD"",
                    ""id"": ""9656a1d2-a434-44c1-ade6-c80f431f4750"",
                    ""path"": ""2DVector"",
                    ""interactions"": """",
                    ""processors"": """",
                    ""groups"": """",
                    ""action"": ""Movement"",
                    ""isComposite"": true,
                    ""isPartOfComposite"": false
                },
                {
                    ""name"": ""up"",
                    ""id"": ""788f5b4c-4d67-471f-9b03-12427bcdae31"",
                    ""path"": ""<Keyboard>/w"",
                    ""interactions"": """",
                    ""processors"": """",
                    ""groups"": """",
                    ""action"": ""Movement"",
                    ""isComposite"": false,
                    ""isPartOfComposite"": true
                },
                {
                    ""name"": ""down"",
                    ""id"": ""b225fbe9-da84-4c5b-9a1e-4267dd8b356d"",
                    ""path"": ""<Keyboard>/s"",
                    ""interactions"": """",
                    ""processors"": """",
                    ""groups"": ""kbm"",
                    ""action"": ""Movement"",
                    ""isComposite"": false,
                    ""isPartOfComposite"": true
                },
                {
                    ""name"": ""left"",
                    ""id"": ""8768e01f-bd1a-4ade-a5f8-d622d12cc09f"",
                    ""path"": ""<Keyboard>/a"",
                    ""interactions"": """",
                    ""processors"": """",
                    ""groups"": ""kbm"",
                    ""action"": ""Movement"",
                    ""isComposite"": false,
                    ""isPartOfComposite"": true
                },
                {
                    ""name"": ""right"",
                    ""id"": ""4a9d104a-6447-4cd4-85f6-6babc26f12c3"",
                    ""path"": ""<Keyboard>/d"",
                    ""interactions"": """",
                    ""processors"": """",
                    ""groups"": ""kbm"",
                    ""action"": ""Movement"",
                    ""isComposite"": false,
                    ""isPartOfComposite"": true
                },
                {
                    ""name"": """",
                    ""id"": ""a64384b9-a9d0-4ea6-b6d4-becb5a64e4df"",
                    ""path"": ""<Gamepad>/rightStick"",
                    ""interactions"": """",
                    ""processors"": """",
                    ""groups"": ""gamepad"",
                    ""action"": ""Aim"",
                    ""isComposite"": false,
                    ""isPartOfComposite"": false
                },
                {
                    ""name"": """",
                    ""id"": ""717d381d-2465-4563-aaaf-ab4166e13c0f"",
                    ""path"": ""<Mouse>/position"",
                    ""interactions"": """",
                    ""processors"": """",
                    ""groups"": ""kbm"",
                    ""action"": ""Aim"",
                    ""isComposite"": false,
                    ""isPartOfComposite"": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    ""controlSchemes"": [
        {
            ""name"": ""kbm"",
            ""bindingGroup"": ""kbm"",
            ""devices"": [
                {
                    ""devicePath"": ""<Keyboard>"",
                    ""isOptional"": false,
                    ""isOR"": false
                },
                {
                    ""devicePath"": ""<Mouse>"",
                    ""isOptional"": false,
                    ""isOR"": false
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            ""name"": ""gamepad"",
            ""bindingGroup"": ""gamepad"",
            ""devices"": [
                {
                    ""devicePath"": ""<Gamepad>"",
                    ""isOptional"": false,
                    ""isOR"": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}");
        // Controls
        m_Controls = asset.FindActionMap("Controls", throwIfNotFound: true);
        m_Controls_Movement = m_Controls.FindAction("Movement", throwIfNotFound: true);
        m_Controls_Aim = m_Controls.FindAction("Aim", throwIfNotFound: true);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        UnityEngine.Object.Destroy(asset);
    }

    public InputBinding? bindingMask
    {
        get => asset.bindingMask;
        set => asset.bindingMask = value;
    }

    public ReadOnlyArray<InputDevice>? devices
    {
        get => asset.devices;
        set => asset.devices = value;
    }

    public ReadOnlyArray<InputControlScheme> controlSchemes => asset.controlSchemes;

    public bool Contains(InputAction action)
    {
        return asset.Contains(action);
    }

    public IEnumerator<InputAction> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return asset.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Enable()
    {
        asset.Enable();
    }

    public void Disable()
    {
        asset.Disable();
    }
    public IEnumerable<InputBinding> bindings => asset.bindings;

    public InputAction FindAction(string actionNameOrId, bool throwIfNotFound = false)
    {
        return asset.FindAction(actionNameOrId, throwIfNotFound);
    }
    public int FindBinding(InputBinding bindingMask, out InputAction action)
    {
        return asset.FindBinding(bindingMask, out action);
    }

    // Controls
    private readonly InputActionMap m_Controls;
    private IControlsActions m_ControlsActionsCallbackInterface;
    private readonly InputAction m_Controls_Movement;
    private readonly InputAction m_Controls_Aim;
    public struct ControlsActions
    {
        private @Playercontrols m_Wrapper;
        public ControlsActions(@Playercontrols wrapper) { m_Wrapper = wrapper; }
        public InputAction @Movement => m_Wrapper.m_Controls_Movement;
        public InputAction @Aim => m_Wrapper.m_Controls_Aim;
        public InputActionMap Get() { return m_Wrapper.m_Controls; }
        public void Enable() { Get().Enable(); }
        public void Disable() { Get().Disable(); }
        public bool enabled => Get().enabled;
        public static implicit operator InputActionMap(ControlsActions set) { return set.Get(); }
        public void SetCallbacks(IControlsActions instance)
        {
            if (m_Wrapper.m_ControlsActionsCallbackInterface != null)
            {
                @Movement.started -= m_Wrapper.m_ControlsActionsCallbackInterface.OnMovement;
                @Movement.performed -= m_Wrapper.m_ControlsActionsCallbackInterface.OnMovement;
                @Movement.canceled -= m_Wrapper.m_ControlsActionsCallbackInterface.OnMovement;
                @Aim.started -= m_Wrapper.m_ControlsActionsCallbackInterface.OnAim;
                @Aim.performed -= m_Wrapper.m_ControlsActionsCallbackInterface.OnAim;
                @Aim.canceled -= m_Wrapper.m_ControlsActionsCallbackInterface.OnAim;
            }
            m_Wrapper.m_ControlsActionsCallbackInterface = instance;
            if (instance != null)
            {
                @Movement.started += instance.OnMovement;
                @Movement.performed += instance.OnMovement;
                @Movement.canceled += instance.OnMovement;
                @Aim.started += instance.OnAim;
                @Aim.performed += instance.OnAim;
                @Aim.canceled += instance.OnAim;
            }
        }
    }
    public ControlsActions @Controls => new ControlsActions(this);
    private int m_kbmSchemeIndex = -1;
    public InputControlScheme kbmScheme
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_kbmSchemeIndex == -1) m_kbmSchemeIndex = asset.FindControlSchemeIndex("kbm");
            return asset.controlSchemes[m_kbmSchemeIndex];
        }
    }
    private int m_gamepadSchemeIndex = -1;
    public InputControlScheme gamepadScheme
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_gamepadSchemeIndex == -1) m_gamepadSchemeIndex = asset.FindControlSchemeIndex("gamepad");
            return asset.controlSchemes[m_gamepadSchemeIndex];
        }
    }
    public interface IControlsActions
    {
        void OnMovement(InputAction.CallbackContext context);
        void OnAim(InputAction.CallbackContext context);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not related to your issue but you refer to your `playerControls` variable in the `OnEnable` method and the `PlayerControls` type in the `OnDisable` method. Is that how it's supposed to be?

Comment: Where exactly is this `PlayerControls` class supposed to be declared? I just did a search in the Unity doco and found nothing, so is it something that you're supposed to be providing? Where is this template that you're copying?

Comment: This seems to be the new Input system where `PlayerControls` would be an auto generated script resulting from according action map. A) Do you have an action map with that name in your project? B) Did you enable the `Generate c# class` option for this action map? See e.g. https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/taking-advantage-of-the-input-system-scripting-api?uv=2020.1&projectId=5fc93d81edbc2a137af402b7#5fcad3efedbc2a0020f781e1

Comment: @John I'm referring to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=koRgU2dC5Po&t=465s from my understanding of the topic I'm 'Using UnityEngine.InputSystem;' to import my playerControls.cs file into my main script, unless I'm totally off the mark.

Comment: @derHugo I posted my 2nd script in OP for clarity. I think I'm starting to see the name resolution errors but I'm not 100% yet.

Comment: Have you tried `@PlayerControls` ? ^^

Comment: Renaming the action map and regenerating the C# script fixed my error. Thanks!